# What is the meaning of Perf events: dTLB-loads and dTLB-stores?

Tags: intel, perf, amd-processor, tlb

I'm trying to understand the meaning of the perf events: dTLB-loads and dTLB-stores?

Comment: Do you know the difference between a load vs. a store operation?  e.g. `add [rdi], eax` is both a load and a store.  (And each part executes separately, so both would be separate TLB references).

Comment: I do understand in general that load fetches from memory and store writes back to memory, but I'm confused about the meaning of a TLB-store. From what I've read TLB entry can get modified (esp. dirty bit or valid bit changed), but where does the store happen to and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When virtual memory is enabled, the virtual address of every single memory access needs to be looked up in the TLB to obtain the corresponding physical address and determine access permissions and privileges (or raise an exception in case of an invalid mapping). The `dTLB-loads` and `dTLB-stores` events represent a TLB lookup for a data memory load or store access, respectively. The is the `perf` definition of these events. but the exact meaning depends on the microarchitecture.

On Westmere, Skylake, Kaby Lake, Coffee Lake, Cannon Lake (and probably Ice Lake), `dTLB-loads` and `dTLB-stores` are mapped to `MEM_INST_RETIRED.ALL_LOADS` and `MEM_INST_RETIRED.ALL_STORES`, respectively. On Sandy Bridge, Ivy Bridge, Haswell, Broadwell, Goldmont, Goldmont Plus, they are mapped to `MEM_UOP_RETIRED.ALL_LOADS` and `MEM_UOP_RETIRED.ALL_STORES`, respectively. On Core2, Nehalem, Bonnell, Saltwell, they are mapped to `L1D_CACHE_LD.MESI` and `L1D_CACHE_ST.MESI`, respectively. (Note that on Bonnell and Saltwell, the official names of the events are `L1D_CACHE.LD` and `L1D_CACHE.ST` and the event codes used by `perf` are only documented in the Intel manual Volume 3 and not in other Intel sources on performance events.) The `dTLB-loads` and `dTLB-stores` events are not supported on Silvermont and Airmont.

On all current AMD processors, `dTLB-loads` is mapped to `LsDcAccesses` and `dTLB-stores` is not supported. However, `LsDcAccesses` counts TLB lookups for both loads and stores. On processors from other vendors, `dTLB-loads` and `dTLB-stores` are not supported.

See [Hardware cache events and perf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52170960/hardware-cache-events-and-perf) for how to map `perf` core events to native events.

The `dTLB-loads` and `dTLB-stores` event counts for the same program on different microarchitectures can be different not only because of differences in the microarchitectures but also because the meaning of the events is itself different. Therefore, even if the microarchitectural behavior of the program turned out to be the same on the microarchitectures, the event counts can still be different. A brief description of the native events on all Intel microarchitectures can be found [here](https://download.01.org/perfmon/index/) and a more detailed description on some of the microarchitectures can be found [here](https://hadibrais.wordpress.com/2019/03/26/an-introduction-to-the-cache-hit-and-miss-performance-monitoring-events/).

Related: [how to interpret perf iTLB-loads,iTLB-load-misses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49933319/how-to-interpret-perf-itlb-loads-itlb-load-misses).

Answer (score 6):

A TLB-store isn't a write *to* the TLB, it's a write to a virtual address in main memory which has to *read* a TLB entry.

So a TLB-store is a TLB-reference that's done by a store operation.