# How to measure the dtlb hits and dtlb misses with perf_event_open()?

Tags: perf, tlb, intel-pmu

I want to measure the cache miss rate and dtlb miss rate.
I have done the first part.

But I can't find how to set the config to get dtlb miss and dtlb hits. 
When I measured the cache miss, I do like this:

```
    pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
    pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
    pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MISSES;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no 'direct' PMU events in `perf`, that will help you measure the `dTLB hits`. There are separate `dTLB miss` events for memory loads and stores, which you can see when you run the below command,

```
sudo perf list | grep 'Hardware cache'

dTLB-load-misses                                   [Hardware cache event]
dTLB-loads                                         [Hardware cache event]
dTLB-store-misses                                  [Hardware cache event]
dTLB-stores                                        [Hardware cache event]
```

The meanings of each of these events have already been mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56175755/). They are dependent on the microarchitecture you are using, and this will matter in the computation of `dTLB-hits`.

Say, for example you are looking to sample the occurrences of event `dTLB-load-misses`,

```
       pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE;
       pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
       pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_DTLB <<  0 | PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ <<  8 | PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS << 16;
```

and if you are looking to measure the occurrences of event `dTLB-loads`,

```
       pe.type = PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE;
       pe.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
       pe.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_DTLB <<  0 | PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ <<  8 | PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_ACCESS << 16;
```

For measuring `dTLB-store-misses` and `dTLB-stores`, you need to replace `PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ` with `PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_WRITE` in the above configs.

When measuring, any of the hardware cache events, the config should always be of the form -

```
pe.config = (perf_hw_cache_id << 0) | (perf_hw_cache_op_id << 8) | (perf_hw_cache_op_result_id << 16)
```

where meanings and different 'enumerated' values of `perf_hw_cache_id`, `perf_hw_cache_op_id` and `perf_hw_cache_op_result_id` are mentioned [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.6.4/source/include/uapi/linux/perf_event.h#L70).

Ideally, depending on your requirement, you'd want to be measuring all of the above four events together for a single workload, so an example of how you can measure `dTLB-load-misses` and `dTLB-loads` together is shown below -

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>
#include <linux/hw_breakpoint.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>


struct read_format {
  uint64_t nr;
  struct {
    uint64_t value;
    uint64_t id;
  } values[];
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  struct perf_event_attr pea;
  int fd1, fd2;
  uint64_t id1, id2;
  uint64_t val1, val2;
  char buf[4096];
  struct read_format* rf = (struct read_format*) buf;
  int i;

  memset(&pea, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
  pea.type = PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE;
  pea.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
  pea.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_DTLB <<  0 | PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ <<  8 | PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_ACCESS << 16;
  pea.disabled = 1;
  pea.exclude_kernel = 1;
  pea.exclude_hv = 1;
  pea.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
  fd1 = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &pea, 0, -1, -1, 0);
  ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &id1);

  memset(&pea, 0, sizeof(struct perf_event_attr));
  pea.type = PERF_TYPE_HW_CACHE;
  pea.size = sizeof(struct perf_event_attr);
  pea.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_DTLB <<  0 | PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_OP_READ <<  8 | PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_RESULT_MISS << 16;;
  pea.disabled = 1;
  pea.exclude_kernel = 1;
  pea.exclude_hv = 1;
  pea.read_format = PERF_FORMAT_GROUP | PERF_FORMAT_ID;
  fd2 = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &pea, 0, -1, fd1 /*!!!*/, 0);
  ioctl(fd2, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ID, &id2);


  ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_RESET, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);
  ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_ENABLE, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);
  sleep(10);
  ioctl(fd1, PERF_EVENT_IOC_DISABLE, PERF_IOC_FLAG_GROUP);


  read(fd1, buf, sizeof(buf));
  for (i = 0; i < rf->nr; i++) {
    if (rf->values[i].id == id1) {
      val1 = rf->values[i].value;
    } else if (rf->values[i].id == id2) {
      val2 = rf->values[i].value;
    }
  }

  printf("dTLB-loads: %"PRIu64"\n", val1);
  printf("dTLB-load-misses: %"PRIu64"\n", val2);

  return 0;
```

Some ideas involved while monitoring multiple events using `perf_event_open` are mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42092180/), from which the above program has been copied.